# How to to validate geometries using ogr2ogr

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql, ogr2ogr

I have been trying to dissolve a shapefile with more than 38000 rows. I used query as follows

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" dissolved.shp Barangays.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_union(Geometry),* from input  GROUP BY concated"
```

It gave me error that geometry is invalid because of self-intersecting polygons.

I found out there are 86 features which have invalid geometries using QGIS. I tried Make Valid tool as suggested in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/how-to-fix-quickly-a-lot-of-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis). But this is also not working, giving error undefined symbol, which I couldn't understand. So I decided to validate using ogr2ogr and after searching through google I tried this query

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" valid_barangays.shp Barangays.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select Geometry.MakeValid(),* from Barangays"
```

It gave me this error

```
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare(select Geometry.MakeValid(),* from Barangays):
  near "(": syntax error
```

How can I solve this problem?

I also imported my shapefile using ogr2ogr in phpmyadmin mysql. It saved geomtry column as [geometry some_number B]. I am not able to query. I always give error function not exist.

Comment: What about using QGIS ?

Comment: @shiko As an automated process?

Comment: @FábioDias in QGIS you can do both, either manually or programmatically using python (Inside QGIS as a plugin or as a standalone application). check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159699/how-to-find-the-irregular-polygons-in-qgis-using-python

Answer (score 6):

Based on the post:
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=liblwgeom-4.0

SpatiaLite should support the ST_MakeValid argument. So this should work. Without your data it is hard to test. But it should work if you specify your geometry within the ST_MakeValid statement

So if you run:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" valid_barangays.shp Barangays.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(geometry) as geometry, * from Barangays"
```

If that does not work, you will likely have to specify each other column instead of selecting *.

Comment: I tried query as suggested by you but I got error no such function: ST_MakeValid

Comment: That means that your version of GDAL is compiled either without SpatiaLite at all or with so old SpatiaLite version that ST_MakeValid was not implemented yet.

Comment: it works nicely!

Answer (score 3):

Using [`makevalid`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-makevalid) parameter could fix your problem:

> **-makevalid**
>
> Run the OGRGeometry::MakeValid() operation, followed by
> OGRGeometryFactory::removeLowerDimensionSubGeoms(), on geometries to
> ensure they are valid regarding the rules of the Simple Features
> specification.

Try:

```
ogr2ogr valid_barangays.shp Barangays.shp -makevalid
```

Comment: this is available departing gdal/ogr > 3.2, which was released in october 2020: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.2.0/gdal/NEWS